# C++-CLI Pipeline only returns the first row of the error message

Tags: c++, powershell, c++-cli

I'm executing exchange powershell commands through a pipeline from my code.

The problem is that when the command is executed on the powershell directly the error returned is four rows long, but when I run the command through the pipeline it only returns the first row of the error message.

This is the code I have so far:

```
bool ps_calls::check_invoke(Pipeline^ pipeline)
{
    if (pipeline->Error->Count <= 0)
        return true;

    Collection<System::Object^> errorCollection =  pipeline->Error->ReadToEnd();
    for (int i=0; i< errorCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        String^ msg = String::Format("Error {0}",errorCollection[i]->ToString());
        m_errors->Add(msg);
        m_logger->info_msg(String::Format("ERROR: {0}", msg));
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is an example of what my pipeline returns now:

```
ERROR: Error The operation couldn't be performed because object 'Testing' couldn't be found on 'server'.
```

This is an example of what the error message is if the same command is executed on the powershell console manually:

```
The operation couldn't be performed because object 'test' couldn't be found on 'server'.

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-MailboxDatabase], ManagementObjectNotFoundException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 2F753561,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.GetMailboxDatabase

    + PSComputerName        : server
```

I would like to be able to get the rest of this error message as well so that I can see the ErrorID when an error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't call ToString when it does formatting, that's why you don't see the same output.

Some host applications typically pipe output to Out-Default - if you did that, you'd see the expected format for errors.

Other host applications will pipe output to Out-String - this will format objects in the same way that the would be formatted if piped to Out-Default, but you'll get a string object that you can log however you need to.

Comment: So you're saying I should change my pipeline output from Out-String to Out-Default? But will I be able to log the format returned by Out-Default?  I'm not in the office right now but will try this out first thing tomorrow morning. Thanks.

Comment: It depends, either may work for you.  You could replace your call 'errorCollection[i]->ToString()' with a pipeline that pipes errorCollection[i] to Out-String.  If your m_logger is connected to a host (PSHost), then Out-Default might be fine.

Comment: Hey Jason thanks for the help. I've tried just adding         pipeline->Commands->Add("Out-String"); before the invoke command is executed and it still returns the same output. Do I have to specifically change the errorCollection[i]->ToString() into a pipeline that outputs to out-string or is what I did an equivalent? And m_logger is not connected to a host sadly but just to a class.

Comment: That would work, but you need to merge the error and output streams, at which point you'll only get strings back with now way of knowing which were errors.  I suggest creating a new pipeline for your error objects and piping those to Out-String.